# virt-manager and opengl

Tags: virt-manager, libvirt

The latest virt-manager 1.4.1 support opengl on spice

But when i check opengl is impossible to check

and said "hypervisor/libvirt does not support manual rendernode"

What I miss?

qemu and libvirt are compiled with virgl support

So virgl is installed,system is Slackware 14.2

Comment: Do you have virglrenderer installed? What system are you using?

Comment: Yes virgl is installed,system is slackware 14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
With the latest virt-manager 2.* and with updated virgl-render
all works fine(slow..but start)
So I think my problem was a bug or misconfiguration.